# Protecting authentication data in WP7 app

Tags: windows-phone-7, authentication, amazon-web-services

I am writing a WP7 app and would like to include features to share highscore data using Amazon's AWS as storage service.

As far as I understand WP7 XAP files are (currently) safely encrypted and no known jailbreak for the phone exists. However, given that such a 'safe' encryption can be temporary, I would like to understand if/how this violates best practice.

AWS' dynamoDB uses temporary access tokens that can be generated using given account data and are valid for 36 hours the tokens must be verified using a signature with any request.

I am considering that all access data will be stored in the XAP file, which will also generate the temporary access token and signature. The information will be passed via https requests between the phone and AWS.

I was trying to work out alternative processes including passing the generation of the temporary token calculation to an external webservice, however I cannot think of a way to protect this data which would not be similarly compromised if the XAP file was accessible.

Am I missing the best practice approach completely or am I just overly cautious?

Thanks.

Comment: "As far as I understand WP7 XAP files are (currently) safely encrypted" Oh no, a XAP file is just a zip file with your assemblies packed inside. Downloading a XAP from the marketplace is child game, and you can them easily decompile the assembly using Reflector.

Comment: Would that mean that there is no way at all to efficiently hide authentication data that is exchanged between a silverlight client and a server?

Comment: I can tell you for sure that no data put directly into your assemblies is safe. Now I'm don't know enough about security to tell whether there's another safe way to hide authentication data on client's side. Rather than allowing your application to directly access the database, can't you create a webservice to act as an additional layer between the app and the database?

Comment: I could, but I am not sure about the benefit. It's really just to store high scores and tell players how good or bad they compare to others. By using my own webservice all I can do is prevent deletions but not prevent people from adding slightly increased high scores. All of that can be done by managing the user account that is passed along with the application to only allow queries/additions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't ever be able to prevent users from sending false scores, pretty much for the same reason as unofficial cheating apps exist for every popular game. The best you can do is making it **harder**.

With a simple approach, the client sends the score directly to the server, without any kind of encryption. Someone can cheat just by running the app on the emulator and capturing the outgoing packets, then opening the same URL on his desktop browser. Estimated time: less than 10 minutes, and it can be done by anyone who knows that he can download XAPs directly from the marketplace, remove the manifest, and deploy it on the emulator.

Then you can add an encryption key on the client. Now someone has to know C# and Reflector to extract it, but it's still easy for someone having those skills.

Next level, you can add an encryption key AND obfuscate the assembly. Knowledge of CIL and Relector are required to extract the key. It'll take 30 minutes to an hour to a highly skilled developper to extract the key, and many hours for most developpers.

Finally, you can add multiple steps to confuse even more the intruder (for instance, downloading a temporary token from a server and using it somehow in the score sending process). Also, you can design the scoring system in a way that some scores are illegal (dumb example: if the minimal scoring action earns 2 points, then if someone sends an odd number as a score you know he's cheating. This one is easy to figure out, but you can make much more complex rules).

In any way, keep in mind that your system will always be vulnerable, it's only a matter of how much time it will take to the attacker to break through it. If it takes many hours or days to a highly skilled developer, then unless you're offering some worthy prize to the best player, you can safely assume that nobody will bother doing that.

Comment: Thanks, I have decided to use obfuscation on the code. I doubt that it's relevant enough for anyone to try and hack it.